# Magento 2.3 | Display specific categories on "list" mode rather than "grid"

Tags: magento2.3

Is there a way to display specific categories on `list` mode rather than the usuall `grid` mode. A few categories of mine would need that due to the product standards and the used `short_description` within them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open desired category edit form in admin, update the `Layout Update XML` value inside the `Design` section this way:

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="setData">
                <argument name="key" xsi:type="string">_current_grid_mode</argument>
                <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

By default you can set `list` or `grid` mode.

Here is result on my staging for category with that layout update:

[image: result on category page]

Keep in mind that path to the `product_list_toolbar` block must be valid for your layout. In my example I'm using default blank theme.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked like a charm :)