# How to set default grid for desktop and default list for mobile

Tags: magento2

Does anyone have any solution to:

- set default `grid` for desktop
- set default `list` for mobile

```
Magento 2.4.2
```

Comment: It's not possible to do that with any configurations, because Magento does not know what is your device on the server side - more than that - it's impossible or very hard to do in most cases. Keep in mind there is a lot of different devices and resolutions and 

It can be somehow achieved using JS, so the change from grid to list (assuming you have grid as default view) is triggered when device is detected, it should work in most cases, but won't be ideal too.

Comment: You can do this by customize the magento default function by creating the plugin of the function which set the mode for the category.

Comment: Here I found one solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301797/magento-2-3-display-specific-categories-on-list-mode-rather-than-grid  but can anyone help me how can I implement it? Because in category edit I not see option to add this code